# When did the Rupert Bear stories start repeating themselves?

Tags: comics, rupert-bear

Some years ago I used to collect [Rupert Bear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rupert_Bear) annuals. I had a huge collection going all the way back to the 1940s, with some gaps which I slowly filled in over the years, and every time I got a new book, it meant reading several new Rupert stories. So I was rather disappointed when at some point (some time in the noughties, I think) they published a new Rupert annual in which at least one of the stories was exactly the same as one previously published - the Yeti story from 1990, if memory serves. But now I'm curious about whether this had any precedent.

**What is the history of reusing Rupert Bear stories?** Was it ever done before? Has it become a regular thing in recent years, or did they do it once and then never again because of fan backlash? For that matter, what *was* the exact year I remember in which they (?) started reusing stories?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**The first time the Rupert Annuals repeated a story was in 1953.** But before the year I remember (2006), there were only seven years in which old stories were repeated (1953, 1982, 1983, 1984, 1985, 1986, 1988), and the only time any story from later than 1940 was repeated was for the 50th anniversary special (1986), which made a point of containing one story from each decade. Since the earliest annual I owned was 1949, this explains why I never noticed repetition until recently.

**The year I remember (2006) was when repetition of old stories really became a trend.** In fact, since 2010, there has been only *one new story each year*, the rest being recycled older stories. Apparently Rupert annuals have gone so far downhill that they're mostly surviving on reruns. I'm glad I got out when I did, so that Rupert can remain a treasured childhood memory without being spoiled.

---

The above conclusions were drawn from examining raw data in the form of all titles of all Rupert stories since the start of modern Rupert in 1936. (I didn't check the earlier Tourtel stories, since the form was so different then that repetition would be impossible: at most, a post-Bestall story might be based on the same *idea* as a Tourtel story, and inspiration is different from wholesale copy-pasting.)

My data was taken from [this site](http://www.rupertbear.co.uk/rupert-annuals_PC5.html) (which has a page for each year, listing that year's story titles and sometimes extra info such as facsimile editions) and [this site](http://www.geocities.ws/gravitygrave/Rupert/) (which has a page for each decade, listing the story titles from every year in that decade). I've cross-referenced the two against each other to check for consistency; in the data below, brackets in story titles denote small differences between the two sources (usually minor things such as uncertain hyphenation) while entire stories in brackets were listed in one source but not the other (there are only two of these). Since my second source only covers the '30s to '90s, all data from 2000 onwards is taken from the first source alone.

It's perhaps not necessary for me to include all my raw data in this answer. I do so, not only to make my research reproducible, but also because this may now be **the only place on the internet with *all* Rupert story titles gathered on a single page**. All my searching hasn't yielded another such page - if there was one, it would have made my data collection far easier and quicker.

### RAW DATA FOLLOWS.

---

- **1936 The New Adventures of Rupert**

  Rupert and the Wonderful Kite
  Rupert, Algy and the Cannibals
  Rupert's Autumn Adventure
  Rupert, Bill and the Pearls
  Rupert's Christmas Adventure
- **1937 More Adventures of Rupert**

  Rupert and the Snow Machine
  Rupert and the Flying Bottle
  Rupert and the Floods
  Rupert and the Little Men
  Rupert, Algy and the Smugglers
  Rupert and the Chinese Crackers
  Rupert and Dog Toby
- **1938 The New Rupert Book**

  Rupert and the (Black) Daffodils
  Rupert, Edward and the Paper Chase
  Rupert in Mysteryland
  Rupert and the Ruby Ring
  Rupert and the Cuckoo Clock
  Rupert and Pong Ping
  Rupert and Peter
  Rupert and Bill in the Treetops
- **1939 The Adventures of Rupert**

  Rupert's Adventures in the Snows
  Rupert and the Jack-in-the-Box
  Rupert's Bonfire
  Rupert and the Strange Airman
  Rupert and the Half Crowns
  Rupert and the Courier Bird
  Rupert and the Goblin Cobbler
  Rupert, Beppo and the Kite
- **1940 Rupert's Adventure Book**

  Rupert and Uncle Bruno
  Rupert, Bill and the Bluebells
  Rupert and the Silver Trowel
  Rupert and the Iceberg
  Rupert and the Air Smugglers
  Rupert's Marvellous Bat
  Rupert and King Frost
  Rupert and the Pedlar
- **1941 The Rupert Book**

  Rupert and the Red Egg
  Rupert and the Baby Badger
  Rupert and the Mystery Pond
  Rupert and the Forest Fire
  Rupert and the Lost Boat
  Rupert and the Little Woodman
  Rupert and the Sugar Bird
- **1942 More Adventures of Rupert**

  Rupert and the Cartwheels
  Rupert and Odmedod
  Rupert and the Wrong Presents
  Rupert and the Old Ruin
  Rupert and the Little Plane
  Rupert and the Sea Serpent
  Rupert and the Fire
  Rupert at Sandy Bay
- **1943 More Rupert Adventures**

  Rupert and the Circus Dog
  Rupert and the Piper
  Rupert and the Banjo
  Rupert's Good Turn
  Rupert and Tiger Lily
  Rupert's Birthday
  Rupert and the Iron Key
  Rupert and Golly
  Rupert and the Black Moth
  Rupert's Big Game Hunt
  Rupert's River Adventure
- **1944 Rupert in More Adventures**

  Rupert and Rollo
  Rupert and the Old Map
  Rupert and the Tiny Flute
  Rupert and the Mystery Voice
  Rupert and the Yellow Cloak
  Rupert and Snuffy
  Rupert and Granny Goat
  Rupert's Rainy Adventure
  Rupert's Strange Party
  Rupert and the Dutch Doll
- **1945 A New Rupert Book**

  Rupert and the Reindeer
  Rupert and the Cuckoo
  Rupert and the Turnips
  Rupert and Jock
  Rupert and Willie
  Rupert's Fairy Cycle
  Rupert and the Music Man
  Rupert's Winter Journey
  Rupert and Bingo's Trail
- **1946 New Rupert Book**

  Rupert on Coon Island
  Rupert and Rastus
  Rupert and the Blue Mountain
  (Rupert and the Prince of China?)
  Rupert, Beppo and the Duck
  Rupert and Podgy
  Rupert and the Rocket Plane
  Rupert and Bingo
  Rupert and the Magic Dart
- **1947 More Adventures of Rupert**

  Rupert and the Top Hat
  Rupert and the Black Cat
  Rupert and the Young Dragon
  Rupert, Bill and the Merboy
  Rupert and the Paper Kettle
  Rupert and the Woffle Fly
  Rupert and Koko
  Rupert and the Wavy Wand
  Rupert's Christmas Tree
- **1948 The Rupert Book**

  Rupert and Jack Frost
  Rupert and the Blue Balloon
  Rupert and the Magic S(t)ock
  Rupert and the Sleepy Pears
  Rupert and Rosalie
  Rupert and the Rainbow
  Rupert's Puppy Hunt
  Rupert and Cedric
  Rupert and the Hobby(-)Horse
- **1949 Rupert**

  Rupert and Ninky
  Rupert and the Young Imp
  Rupert's Magic Top
  Rupert's Island Adventure
  Rupert and Uncle Grizzly
  Rupert and the Twins
  Rupert and the New Pal
  Rupert, Algy and the Bee
  Rupert and Pong(-)Ping's Party
- **1950 Adventures of Rupert**

  Rupert's Silver Trumpet
  Rupert and Margot's House/Horse
  Rupert and the Jumping Fish
  Rupert and the Gooseberry Fool
  Rupert and the Paper Plane
  Rupert and the Three Guides
  Rupert and the Travel Machine
  Rupert and the Big Bang
  Rupert and the Empty Cottage
- **1951 The New Rupert Rook**

  Rupert and Dr Lion
  Rupert and Ting(-)Ling
  Rupert and Mr Punch
  Rupert and the Lucky Man
  Rupert's Elfin Bell
  Rupert and the Runaways
  Rupert's Queer Path
  Rupert's Dull Day
- **1952 More Rupert Adventures**

  Rupert and the Mare's Nest
  Rupert and the Sea(-)Sprites
  Rupert and the Elephants
  Rupert and the Arrows
  Rupert, Beppo and the Caravan
  Rupert and the Snuff(-)box
- **1953 More Adventures of Rupert**

  Rupert and Miranda
  Rupert and the Green Buzzer
  Rupert, Algy and the Cannibals (**1936**)
  Rupert and the Missing Pieces
  Rupert in Mysteryland (**1938**)
  Rupert at Rocky Bay
- **1954 The New Rupert**

  Rupert and the Friendly Sea(-)Lion
  Rupert and the Sketch Book
  Rupert and the Castaway
  Rupert and the Backroom Boy
  Rupert and the Dragon Pills
- **1955 Rupert**

  Rupert and (the) Poll Parrot
  Rupert and the Blue Firework
  Rupert and the Autumn Primrose
  Rupert and the Unknown Journey
  Rupert and the Cough Drop
- **1956 The Rupert Book**

  Rupert and the Blue Moon
  Rupert and Unlucky Simon
  Rupert and the Bandits' Cave (aka Rupert's Climbing Adventure)
  Rupert and the Flying Sorcerer
- **1957 Rupert**

  Rupert and the Crackerjack
  Rupert and the Pine Ogre
  Rupert and the Lion Rock
  Rupert and the Wind Whistle
- **1958 Rupert**

  Rupert and the Water(-)Lily
  Rupert and the New Bonnet
  Rupert and the Ice Flowers
  Rupert and the Spring Adventure
  Rupert and the Train Journey
- **1959 Rupert**

  Rupert and the Copper Bird
  Rupert and the River Rescue
  Rupert and the Butterflies
  Rupert and the Hazel Nut
  Rupert and the Toy Scout
- **1960 Rupert**

  Rupert and the Crystal
  Rupert and Morwenna
  Rupert and Ozzie
  Rupert and the Diamond Leaf
- **1961 Rupert**

  Rupert and the Hearth(-)Rug
  Rupert and the Pepper Rose
  Rupert and the Black Spark
  Rupert and the New Boat
  Rupert at/and Greyrocks Cove
- **1962 Rupert**

  Rupert and the Dragon Fly
  Rupert and the Robins
  Rupert and Niagara
  Rupert and the Bad Dog
  Rupert and the Coral Island
- **1963 Rupert**

  Rupert and the Birthday Present
  Rupert and the Golden Acorn
  Rupert and the Lost Cuckoo
  Rupert and the Inventor
  Rupert and the Cold(-)Cure
- **1964 Rupert**

  Rupert and the Dover Sole
  Rupert and the Distant Music
  Rupert and the Compass
  Rupert and the Dog(-)Roses
  Rupert and the Rock Pool
- **1965 Rupert**

  Rupert and (the) Gaffer
  Rupert and the Winter Woolley
  Rupert and the Old Hat
  Rupert and Rusty
- **1966 Rupert**

  Rupert and the Magic Ball
  Rupert and the Secret Boat
  Rupert and (the) Billy Goat
  Rupert and the Spring Chicken
- **1967 Rupert**

  Rupert and the Lost List
  Rupert and the Jackdaw
  Rupert and Floppity
  Rupert and the Carved Stick
- **1968 Rupert**

  Rupert and (the) Truant
  Rupert and the Fiddle
  Rupert and the Fire(-)bird
  Rupert and the Rolling Ball
- **1969 Rupert**

  Rupert and the Whistlefish
  Rupert and the Old Chimney
  Rupert and the Snowball
  Rupert and Raggety
  Rupert and the Fishing Rod
- **1970**

  Rupert and the Outlaws
  Rupert and the Blunderpuss
  Rupert and the Paper Fall
  Rupert and the Sky(-)Boat
- **1971 Rupert**

  Rupert and the Gomnies
  Rupert and the Popweed
  Rupert and the Early Bird
  Rupert and the Windlings
- **1972 Rupert**

  Rupert's Deep Sea Adventure
  Rupert and the Learner
  Rupert and the Rugger Match
  Rupert and Gwyneth
- **1973 Rupert**

  Rupert and the Bouncers
  Rupert and the Housemouse
  Rupert and the Waterfall
  Rupert and the Flying Boat
- **1974 Rupert**

  Rupert and the Iron Spade
  Rupert and Jenny Frost
  Rupert and the Secret Path
  Rupert and the Little Bells
- **1975 Rupert**

  Rupert and the Little River
  Rupert and the Thinking Cap
  Rupert and the Broken Plate
  Rupert and the Blue Star
  Rupert and the Winter Sale
- **1976 Rupert**

  Rupert and the Jumping Men
  Rupert and Young Kevin
  Rupert and the Hot Water
  Rupert and the Windy Day
- **1977 Rupert**

  Rupert and the Winkybickies
  Rupert and the Fire-Lighter
  Rupert and Septimus
  Rupert and the Silent Land
- **1978 Rupert**

  Rupert and the Rivals
  Rupert and the Squire
  Rupert and the Boffit
  Rupert and the Secret Shell
  Rupert's Odd Party
- **1979 Rupert**

  Rupert and the Penguins
  Rupert and the Moon Moths
  Rupert and the Ice Skates
  Rupert and the Capricorn
- **1980 Rupert**

  Rupert and the Flavours
  Rupert and the Mixed Magic
  Rupert and the Blizzard
  Rupert and the Ocean Office
- **1981 Rupert**

  Rupert and the Castle Trap
  Rupert and the Wicked Uncle
  Rupert and the Buzzing Box
  Rupert and the Wrong Sweets
  (Rupert and the Silent Dog?)
  Rupert and the Baby Cloud
- **1982 Rupert**

  Rupert and Pong(-)Ping (**1938**)
  Rupert and the Umbrella Boy
  Rupert and the Gemlins
  Rupert and the Snow Puzzle
  Rupert and the Red Box
- **1983 Rupert**

  Rupert and the Black Circle
  Rupert and the Dragon Race
  Rupert and Santa Paws
  Rupert's Autumn Adventure (**1936**)
- **1984 Rupert**

  Rupert and the Two Moons
  Rupert and the Wee Man
  Rupert and the Igloo
  Rupert and the Wonderful Kite (**1936**)
  Rupert and the Cuckoo Clock (**1938**)
- **1985 Rupert**

  *(note: this 50th anniversary special made a point of containing one story from the 30s, one from the 40s, and so on, so they had a good excuse for repetition in this case)*

  Rupert, Bill and the Pearls (**1936**)
  Rupert at/and Pong-Ping's Party (**1949**)
  Rupert and the Unknown Journey (**1955**)
  Rupert and the Snowstorm
  Rupert and the Pirate Boys
  Rupert and the Windmill
- **1986 Rupert**

  Rupert and the Strange Airman (**1939**)
  Rupert and Rika
  Rupert and the Worried Elves
  Rupert and the Dragon Mystery
  Rupert and the Mulp Gulper
  Rupert and the Iceberg (**1940**)
- **1987 Rupert**

  Rupert and the River Pirates
  Rupert and the Worg Seeds
  Rupert and the Lotus Isle
  Rupert and Hamish
  Rupert and Old Tom's Trove
- **1988 Rupert**

  Rupert on Um Island
  Rupert and the Go-Cart
  Rupert and the Sleeping Village
  Rupert, Beppo and the Kite (**1939**)
  Rupert and Terry's Return
  Rupert and Podgy's Christmas
- **1989 Rupert**

  Rupert and the Boomerarrow
  Rupert and the Knight
  Rupert and the Thaw
  Rupert and the Power Flower
  Rupert and Algy's Misadventure
  Rupert and Rika's Return
- **1990 Rupert**

  Rupert and Little Yum
  Rupert and the Sea Queen
  Rupert and the Eastern Isle
  Rupert and the Little Train
  Rupert and Willie's Present
- **1991 Rupert**

  Rupert and the Angry Sea
  Rupert and the Sacred Crows
  Rupert and the River Rogues
  Rupert and the Twilight Fan
  Rupert and the Stolen Snowman
- **1992 Rupert**

  Rupert and the Falling Leaf
  Rupert and the Wool Gatherers
  Rupert and the Sea Urchin
  Rupert and the Gardens Mystery
  Rupert and the Missing Snow
- **1993 Rupert**

  Rupert and Ottoline
  Rupert and the Chinese Creeper
  Rupert and the Rosalie's Adventure
  Rupert and the Sands of Time
  Rupert and the April Fool
- **1994 Rupert**

  Rupert and the Spaceship
  Rupert and the Peacock Hedge
  Rupert and the Beachcombers
  Rupert and the Queen's Visit
  Rupert and Uncle Boris
- **1995 The Rupert Annual**

  Rupert and the Pharaoh's Treasure
  Rupert and the Star Gazer
  Rupert and the Odmedod's Adventure
  Rupert and the Noisy Firework
  Rupert and the Christmas Tree
- **1996 The Rupert Annual**

  Rupert and the Dragon Dance
  Rupert and the Lost Sheep
  Rupert and the Pirates
  Rupert and the Mail Train
  Rupert and the Deep Freeze
- **1997 The Rupert Annual**

  Rupert and the Song Snatcher
  Rupert and the Magic Chalk
  Rupert and the Whale
  Rupert and the Water Boatman
  Rupert and Santa's Present
- **1998 The Rupert Annual**

  Rupert and the Missing Cakes
  Rupert and the Goose Chase
  Rupert and the Raft
  Rupert and the Sundial
  Rupert and the Pumpkin Pie
  Rupert and Uncle Polar
- **1999 The Rupert Annual**

  Rupert and the Forest Throne
  Rupert and the Gold-Rush
  Rupert and the Skylark
  Rupert and the Apple Trees
  Rupert and the Christmas List
- **2000 The Rupert Annual**

  Rupert and the Fool's Prize
  Rupert and the Rust Mites
  Rupert and the Strawberries
  Rupert and the Harvest Moon
  Rupert and the Smokescreen
  Rupert and the Christmas Cake
- **2001 The Rupert Annual**

  Rupert and the Coronation
  Rupert and the Seaweed
  Rupert's Birthday Adventure
  Rupert and the Pearl Fishers
  Rupert and the Nut Hatch
  Rupert and the Christmas Box
- **2002 The Rupert Annual**

  Rupert and the Broken Wand
  Rupert and the Artist
  Rupert and the Whizz Watch
  Rupert and the Cloud Catchers
  Rupert and the Christmas Play
  Rupert and the Christmas Fairy
- **2003 The Rupert Annual**

  Rupert and the Water Bottle
  Rupert and the Ringer
  Rupert and the Late Start
  Rupert and the Lost Shell
  Rupert and the Blue Vase
  Rupert and the White Path
- **2004 The Rupert Annual**

  Rupert and the Sky Pirates
  Rupert and the Golden Pipe
  Rupert and the Summer Roses
  Rupert and the Runaway Balloon
  Rupert and the Screen
  Rupert and the Reindeer Rescue
- **2005 The Rupert Annual**

  Rupert and the Speaking Pool
  Rupert and the Wind Chimes
  Rupert and the Sum Bean
  Rupert and the Secret
  Rupert and the Golden Apples
  Rupert and the Sparklers
  Rupert and the Gaffer's Guest
- **2006 The Rupert Annual**

  Rupert and the Chimney Sweeper
  Rupert and the Peacock Hedge (**1994**)
  Rupert and the Presents Mix-up
  Rupert and the Missing Snowmen
  Rupert and Little Yum (**1990**)
- **2007 The Rupert Annual**

  Rupert and the Sleeping Village (**1988**)
  Rupert and the Little Train (**1990**)
  Rupert and Algy's Misadventure (**1989**)
  Rupert and Podgy's Christmas (**1988**)
  Rupert and the Metal Horse
- **2008 The Rupert Annual**

  Rupert and the Ice-Cream Van
  Rupert and the Fairy Tales
  Rupert and the Branch Line
- **2009 The Rupert Annual**

  Rupert and the Dam
  Rupert and the Golden Carp
  Rupert and the Lost Sheep (**1996**)
  Rupert and the Cut
- **2010 The 75th Rupert Annual**

  Rupert at School
  Rupert's Queer Path (**1951**)
  Rupert's Birthday Surprise
  Rupert and the Snowbird
- **2011 The Rupert Annual**

  Rupert and the Little Plane (**1942**)
  Rupert and Ozzie (**1960**)
  Rupert and the Mail Train (**1996**)
  Rupert and Robo
- **2012 The Rupert Annual**

  Rupert and the Blue Moon (**1956**)
  Rupert and the River Pirates (**1987**)
  Rupert and the Bosun's Chair
- **2013 The Rupert Annual**

  Rupert and the Cart Race
  Rupert and the Rugger Match (**1972**)
  Rupert and the Baby Cloud (**1981**)
  Rupert and the Missing Snow (**1992**)
- **2014 The Rupert Annual**

  Rupert and the Boffit (**1978**)
  Rupert and the Ocean Office (**1980**)
  Rupert and the Nut Hatch (**2001**)
  Rupert and Snowflake
- **2015 The 80th Rupert Annual**

  Rupert and the Mulp Gulper (**1986**)
  Rupert and the Coral Crown
  Rupert and the Noisy Firework (**1995**)
  Rupert and the Carved Stick (**1967**)
  Rupert and Santa Paws (**1983**)
  Rupert and the Christmas Box (**2001**)
- **2016 The Rupert Annual**

  Rupert and the Iceberg (**1940, 1986**)
  Rupert and the Fiddle (**1968**)
  Rupert and the Gardens Mystery (**1992**)
  Rupert and the Gemlins (**1982**)
  Rupert and the Snowball (**1969**)
  Rupert and the Green Man
- **2017 The Rupert Annual**

  Rupert and the Boomerarrow (**1989**)
  Rupert and the Pepper-Rose (**1961**)
  Rupert and the Secret Shell (**1978**)
  Rupert and the Sundial (**1998**)
  Rupert and the Snow Puzzle (**1982**)
  Rupert and the Christmas Birds
  Rupert and the Goblin Cobbler (**1939**)
- **2018 The Rupert Annual**

  Rupert and the Sugar Bird (**1941**)
  Rupert and the May Queen
  Rupert and the Coral Island (**1962**)
  Rupert and the Turnips (**1945**)
  Rupert and Bill in the Treetops (**1938**)
  Rupert and the Flavours (**1980**)
  Rupert and the Christmas Tree (**1995**)
- **2019 The Rupert Annual**

  Rupert and the Go-Cart (**1988**)
  Rupert and the Skylark (**1999**)
  Rupert and the Wonderful Kite (**1936, 1984**)
  Rupert and the Bearcycle
  Rupert and the Windmill (**1985**)
  Rupert and the Deep Freeze (**1996**)
- **2020 The Rupert Annual**

  Rupert's Deep Sea Adventure (**1972**)
  Rupert and the Rainbow (**1948**)
  Rupert and the Apple Trees (**1999**)
  Rupert and the Pumpkin Pie (**1998**)
  Rupert and the Time Machine
  Rupert and the Stolen Snowmen (**1991**)

Comment: Thanks for this. I can remember reading Rupert and Little Yum to the daughter of close friends in 1990. It was her favourite story. She was only 4 years old (iirc) and I had to explain to her the concept of anthropomorphism, and how animals that ought to be free spirits can be treated as property. That was a hard sell.

Comment: You could give a special mention to the stories that were repeated more than once. For instance, Rupert and the Iceberg from 1940 was repeated in 1986 as well as 2016.

Comment: @MrLister Good point; I edited the 2016 line to mention 1986 as well as 1940.